# Message a user in Slack without touching a mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, slack

**What is a quick and reliable set of key strokes to send a message to a user or channel in Slack?**

In "Good Olde Days" when Skype was a major tool for online chatting, I used to do the following to send a message to a Skype user or chat:

- Use global keyboard shortcut for "Search" in Skype (configurable) which brings the Skype main window with focus set to search text box
- Start typing the name
- Use down arrow key to select the user or chat
- Hit Enter to open the chat
- Type a message and then "Enter" (or Ctrl+Enter) to send.

Since I never had to touch a mouse of a touchpad, it took only 3.1416 instants to do do this.

With Slack is a f___king hell to scroll with a mouse/touchpad and look for a chat of person (makes me wanna pop my eyes out).

I know I can use Ctrl+Shift+e (which works only occasionally) to bring up search interface.  But when I find a person there, then I'm stuck.  It doesn't allow search for channels either.

Answer (score 2):

```
/msg @someuser test
/msg #somechannel test
```

or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, enter some user or channel, press enter, start typing message.

You can write `/shortcuts` to get a list of shortcuts, or just google "slack shortcuts" to find out [lots of useful stuff like this](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201374536-Slack-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: Wow!  Exactly as I want it.  Thank you!  I wonder how I managed to miss this shortcut.